# no match for 'operator=' (operand types are '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<Sommet>>::value_type {aka Sommet}' and 'int')

Tags: c++14

I know I'm probably just stupid and that this error comes from not overloading something but I just can't seem to find a way out of this mess...
Especially since its a code I already used in the pasted that never gave me problems...

The code in itself is pretty simple (a basic BFS) and the error comes on line **524**

```
    std::vector<Sommet> Graphe::BFS(int val_s0)
{
    std::queue<Sommet> maListe;
    std::vector<Sommet> predecesseurs;
    for(auto elem: m_sommet)
        elem.set_couleur(false);

    Sommet s;
    for(int i=0; i<m_ordre; i++)
    {
        predecesseurs.push_back(s);
    }
    Sommet s0 = m_sommet[val_s0];
    maListe.push(s0);
    m_sommet[val_s0].set_couleur(true);
    while(!maListe.empty())
    {
        Sommet top = maListe.front();
        maListe.pop(); 

        top = m_sommet[top.get_id()];

        for(auto elem : top.getAdj())
        {
            if(m_sommet[elem.get_id()].get_couleur() == false)
            {
                maListe.push(elem);
                m_sommet[elem.get_id()].set_couleur(true); 

                 ///ERROR at following line
                predecesseurs[elem.get_id()] = top.get_id(); 
            }
        }
    }
    return predecesseurs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign an ID to a vector element of type `Sommet`. You should either make your `predecesseurs` a vector of `int`s and store IDs there, or keep it a vector of `Sommet` objects, and set the actual objects into it.

Note that your current code pushes an empty predecessor in the loop, which may not be what you are looking for.